# Calculating max difference between consecutive elements in a specific column of a list of lists in Python without pandas

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, arraylist, static-methods

I have array that is a list of lists. Each list index of the list is representative of a specific 'column' of data. I need to find the max difference between any two consecutive elements in 1 specific column. I need to do this with out using pandas which is why it has became difficult. I essentially am dealing with what would be a data frame in pandas but because I can't use it I have a list of ordered lists.

Again I need to do this with out using pandas so I need a calculation that would go over an array like a dataframe.

Below is a portion of the data set I am using. Each element in each list is representative of a specific column. I need to work with the elements in position 5 and calculate the max difference between two consecutive values in this index.

```
info= json_data['dataset_data']['data']
print(info)

[['2017-12-29', 51.76, 51.94, 51.45, 51.76, None, 34640.0, 1792304.0, None, None, None], ['2017-12-28', 51.65, 51.82, 51.43, 51.6, None, 40660.0, 2099024.0, None, None, None], ['2017-12-27', 51.45, 51.89, 50.76, 51.82, None, 57452.0, 2957018.0, None, None, None], ['2017-12-22', 51.05, 51.5, 50.92, 51.32, None, 71165.0, 3641949.0, None, None, None], ['2017-12-21', 51.16, 51.52, 50.9, 51.4, None, 120649.0, 6179433.0, None, None, None], ['2017-12-20', 51.88, 52.04, 51.2, 51.27, None, 50587.0, 2610258.0, None, None, None], ['2017-12-19', 52.73, 52.73, 51.07, 51.66, None, 137313.0, 7102361.0, None, None, None], ['2017-12-18', 52.37, 52.75, 51.61, 52.62, None, 129733.0, 6770499.0, None, None, None],
```

Below is the code I tried to use first

```
x= []
for i in info[4]:
    if i is not None:
        x.append(i[4] - i[4])
max_closing = max(x)
print(max_closing)
```

I also need to find a mean for this column as with the same 'no pandas' restraints.

Any input would be helpful.

Comment: Are you able to use numpy? Also, could you explain how the code you tried didn't do what you wanted/expected?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you just need to ignore the rows that have None in the necessary column, the implementation can be like this:

```
column_number = 4 # you can perform the same calculation on a different column by changing this number or accepting it as an function parameter
# initialise necessary variables
prev_value = None
max_diff = 0

# iterate over all rows in the dataset
for idx in range(len(info)):
    # retrieve the next row
    current_value = info[idx][column_number]
    
    # validate and reset values
    if prev_value is None:
        prev_value = current_value
        continue
    if current_value is None:
        continue
    
    # find the difference and compare it to the current max value (similarly add sum calculation to find the mean later)
    diff = current_value - prev_value
    if diff > max_diff:
        max_diff = diff
    
    # make the current value previous for the next iteration
    prev_value = current_value
```